# Why is the bound `T: 'a` required in order to store a reference `&'a T`?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Given this code:

```
struct RefWrapper<'a, T> {
    r: &'a T,
}
```

... the compiler complains:

> error: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
>
> consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'a` so that the reference type `&'a T` does not outlive the data it points at.

I've seen this error multiple times already and so far I just listened to the compiler and everything worked out fine. However, thinking more about it, I don't understand *why* I have to write `T: 'a`.

As far as I understand, it is *already* impossible to get such a reference. Having `&'a T` implies that there is an object of type `T` that lives for at least `'a`. But we can't store any references in said object which point to data having a shorter lifetime than `'a`. This would *already* result in a compiler error.

In that sense it is already impossible to get a `&'a T` where `T` does not outlive `'a`. Thus the additional annotation (`T: 'a`) shouldn't be necessary.

Am I right? Am I wrong and if yes: how could I break code, if `T: 'a` would not be required?

---

Links:

- [RFC introducing the syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0192-bounds-on-object-and-generic-types.md)
- [Another maybe related RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1214-projections-lifetimes-and-wf.md)

Comment: I asked on #rust and it seems that [this code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24622#issuecomment-94761287) would break things, if the `T: 'a` requirement was lifted. But I don't really understand that code yet and I will stop trying for now. Hopefully someone who understands the issue answers in the meantime ^_^

Comment: [Related RFC from August 2017](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2093)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is part of the well-formedness rules. The type `&'a T` is only well-formed if `T: 'a` (“T outlives 'a”; it is required because we have a reference which we can access during the scope `'a`; the pointed-to value in `T` needs to be valid for at least that scope, too).

`struct RefWrapper<'a, T>` is a generic type and it says you can input a lifetime `'x` and a type `U` and get a `RefWrapper<'x, U>` type back. However, this type is not necessarily well-formed or even implemented unless the requirement `T: 'a` is respected.

This requirement comes from an implementation detail; it's not necessarily so that `T` and `'a` are used together like `&'a T` in the struct's internals. The well formedness requirement needs to be promoted to the public interface of the `RefWrapper` struct, so that the requirements of forming a `RefWrapper<'_, _>` type are public, even if the internal implementation is not.

(There are other places where the same requirement `T: 'a` comes back but is implict:

```
pub fn foo<'a, T>(x: &'a T) { }
```

we spot a difference: here the type `&'a T` is part of the public api, too.)

Answer (score 15):

Congratulations, you were right! As of Rust 1.31, thanks to [RFC 2093, Infer `T: 'x` outlives requirements on structs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2093-infer-outlives.md), the requirement on the user to type out this restriction has been removed:

> Remove the need for explicit `T: 'x` annotations on structs. We will infer their presence based on the fields of the struct. In short, if the struct contains a reference, directly or indirectly, to `T` with lifetime `'x`, then we will infer that `T: 'x` is a requirement

Basically, there wasn't a case where this wasn't required, so there wasn't much value in forcing the programmer to write it out.