# Does a lifetime specified on a reference represent how long the reference or the object is going to live?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```rust
pub struct Foo<'m, T> {
    tx: &'m mut T,
}
```

Here, is `'m` representing the lifetime of the reference `tx` or is it specifying how long the `T` is going to last?

**I believe** that it's the former and it means the lifetime of the object of type `T` that `tx` is referring to must exceed `'m`. Is this the correct understanding?

Answer (score 1):

`&'a T` means "I know that a valid value of type `T` exists at the address contained in this reference for at least as long as the region of code demarcated by `'a`".

---

The full answer depends on:

1. what you think "live" and "lifetime" mean
2. what you mean by "lifetime of the reference"

As stated in [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/155423), the "lifetime" of a value is not what most people expect:

> As an analogy, think of it this way: During a person's life, they will reside in many different locations, each with a distinct address. A Rust lifetime is concerned with the address you currently reside at, not about whenever you will die in the future (although dying also changes your address). Every time you move it's relevant because your address is no longer valid.

A non-reference value has one or more lifetimes associated with it between when it is created and when it is destroyed, but on a single line of code it has only one that is relevant.

A reference has **two** lifetimes associated with it on a single line of code:

1. How long the reference value itself is valid at the current memory address.
2. How long the referred-to value is valid at its current memory address.

Here, the concrete lifetime of `a` is [0, 2]. The concrete lifetime of `b` is [1, 2]. Since `b` refers to `a`, that's *also* a related lifetime:

```rust
fn example() {
    let a = 42;               // 0  A
    let b = &a;               // 1  |  B
    println!("{}, {}", a, b); // 2  |  |
}
```

As the reference depth increases, this continues — `&&&&i32` has five associated lifetimes.

*Most of the time*, this doesn't matter because the compiler will automatically collapse lifetimes... when variance allows for it.

Additionally, since your example uses generic types, it's effectively expanded to:

```rust
pub struct Foo<'m, T: 'm> {
    tx: &'m mut T,
}
```

That is, if the generic type `T` contains any references, they must equal or outlive the lifetime `'m`.

See also:

- [Why does linking lifetimes matter only with mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/155423)
- [Why is the bound `T: 'a` required in order to store a reference `&'a T`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41794800/155423)
- [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: `'m` is the lifetime of the reference. And, since the reference must live to be valid for `'m`, the object it's referencing must live at least as long as `'m`. You can see this in the compiler errors:

This code that tries to create a `'static` reference from a temporary string:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: &'static String = &"foo".to_string();
}
```

errors since the string doesn't live as long as the reference:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:31
  |
2 |     let x: &'static String = &"foo".to_string();
  |            ---------------    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |            |
  |            type annotation requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
3 | }
  | - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

A lifetime on the object itself would be denoted with the lifetime in a generic syntax:

```rust
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    slice_iter: std::slice::Iter<'a, u32>
}
```